# Why is System.AccessToken is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet in a Release in Azure DevOps?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I am building a task in my Release in Azure DevOps. In this task, I have a Powershell script I am running that needs to call some of Azure's Web APIs and so forth so I have a parameter to pass in the AccessToken. But I am getting the following error:

> System.AccessToken : The term 'System.AccessToken' is not recognized as the 
>   name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
>   correct and try again.

Here is what my parameter that I am passing in looks like. 
`-AccessToken "$(System.AccessToken)"`

Why is this happening? Is there a work around?

Comment: Very agree with @scorpio's answer. You may missing enable the checkbox **Allow scripts to access the OAuth token**. Only enable it, then the variable could be exists during the pipeline.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to enable access to OAuth token in your agent job

See this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#access-to-oauth-token